# Remove ruby gems from /usr/bin after rvm install

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems, debian, rvm

I recently installed `rvm` and uninstalled my Debian's `ruby1.8`, though I think `ruby2.1` is still installed. I am left with a lot of executables in /usr/bin and /usr/local/bin from (I think) debian's ruby. How can I delete those?

When I use `gem uninstall`, rvm is used, and thinks I want to remove the gems from `~/.rvm/...`. Also, I sometimes have problems, like when invoking rake:

```
/usr/bin/env: ruby1.9.1: No such file or directory
```

which, by the way, is not to be found (first) found where it should be:

```
$ whereis rake
 > rake: /usr/bin/rake2.1 /usr/local/bin/rake /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/rake /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/rake
```

Can I simply `rm -rf` the gems in `/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin`, and other ruby locations (except for `~/.rvm/**`)? What else is leftover from the defunct ruby install?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but it's worth clarifying that there aren't any gems in `/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin`. Gems can install their *executables* in those locations, e.g. `/usr/bin/rake`, but that's a very small file that uses code from the `gems` directory, which is not under `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`. It depends on the particulars of your Ruby configuration, but the gems themselves could be in e.g.  `/var/lib/gems` or `/usr/lib/ruby/gems`.

Comment: You are most definitely right, I mixed things up. Question updated.

Comment: According to [this article](http://ruby-journal.com/how-to-uninstall-all-ruby-gems/) with Rubygems 2.1+ you can run `gem uninstall --all` to uninstall all gems. The `gem` command also takes `--install-dir` and `--bindir` arguments if it doesn't know where to find them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as pointed out by Jordan, the files in `/usr/local/bin` were nothings but scripts loading the gems. The following got rid of them:

`cat /usr/local/bin/* | grep -lr RubyGems | sudo xargs rm`

since they all start with a few commented lines mentioning RubyGems. My `rake` problem came from the fact that `/usr/local/bin` was before `rvm`'s directories in my path, and still full of old debian's rubygems' files (and the shabang referenced debian's uninstalled ruby). The gems themselves were long gone.

The only question left is: isn't debian's RubyGems/Ruby supposed to clean `/usr/local/bin` when uninstalled? If anybody has an answer for that, I'll gladly mark it as so, if not I'll accept this post.